# Change ShowPhysics Outline Color

Tags: swift, colors, sprite-kit, physics, skspritenode

Is there a way of changing or assigning specific showphysics colors, when showphysics = true?

When showphysics = true in my app, one showphysics body will always be blue and all others will always be green. What I would like to do is depending on the physics body's categoryBitMask is assign specific showphysics colors to easily identify the physics body type.

I have scanned the internet and have not found anything, however I might be mistaken, but I thought I was watching a tutorial where one of the showphysics colors was purple, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a physics body's `dynamic` property is `true`, the outline will be blue. If it is `false`, the outline will be green. You cannot manually set the color.

Comment: That explains the two colors I'm getting. Thanks for the clarification.